# jQuery content slider with bring to front and swipe

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I'm looking for a content slider that will bring to front the clicked on (or swiped to) div.
Something like http://cdn.mediaeventservices.com/Slideflow1.1/gallery.html

That plugin is written in prototype, is there anything for jquery that can do that?
I've been googling for hours...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one http://www.webdevelopers.eu/shop/5/demo

Comment: Thanks but This seems more of a image thing, also not swipable,